# Log In form for different screens

Tags: zurb-foundation

Here is my form:

```
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 small-centered columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="medium-3 columns">
                <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Username:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="medium-9 columns">
                <input type="text" id="right-label" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="medium-3 columns">
                <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Password:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="medium-9 columns">
                <input type="text" id="right-label" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="columns">
                <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" class="right"><label for="checkbox1" class="right">Remember Me</label>
            </div>
        </div>

         <div class="row">
            <div class="columns">
                <input type="submit" class="button right" value="Log In">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I have two questions:

1. The username and password labels sit to the left of the inputs using the right class, how can I switch this off when the screen size is small? I would like the labels to be centered at this break point.
2. I would like the button to be it's regular size apart from on small, where it should expand to fill the row. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Visibility classes let you show or hide elements based on screen size or device orientation. You can use visibility classes to control which elements users see depending on their browsing environment.

```
<p class="panel">
  <strong class="show-for-small-only">This text is shown only on a small screen.</strong>
  <strong class="show-for-medium-up">This text is shown on medium screens and up.</strong>
  <strong class="show-for-medium-only">This text is shown only on a medium screen.</strong>
  <strong class="show-for-large-up">This text is shown on large screens and up.</strong>
  <strong class="show-for-large-only">This text is shown only on a large screen.</strong>
  <strong class="show-for-xlarge-up">This text is shown on xlarge screens and up.</strong>
  <strong class="show-for-xlarge-only">This text is shown only on an xlarge screen.</strong>
  <strong class="show-for-xxlarge-up">This text is shown on xxlarge screens and up.</strong>
</p>
```

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html